# Micronaut gRPC and Micronaut Management

Tags: micronaut, grpc-java

I am currently in the process of writing up a new application using Micronaut and gRPC. Deployment-wise, I am planning on having this run at a Kubernetes cluster, which in turn means that I would like to enable the management endpoints (for liveliness probes and so on).

I am following the documentation [here](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-grpc/latest/guide/) which seem to state that simple adding the `management` dependency would automatically expose the various endpoints (granted with the appropriate `application.yml` properties). I have done that, but I am still unable to access any kind of management endpoint.

For reference my `application.yml` looks like so:

```yaml
---
endpoints:
  health:
    enabled: true
    sensitive: false
    details-visible: ANONYMOUS
  loggers:
    enabled: true
    write-sensitive: false
  threaddump:
    enabled: true
    sensitive: false
```

And my `build.gradle` file looks like so:

`implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-management")`

What am I missing for this to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things to check. First, make sure you have have the below dependencies configured:

```
annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java"
annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
compile "io.micronaut.grpc:micronaut-grpc-runtime"
compile 'io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty'
compile 'io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client'
compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject"
compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
compile "io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime"
compile "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api"
runtime "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
```

Next, while this isn't mandatory, add the following in the `application.yml` file:

```
micronaut:
  server:
    port: <http-1.x port>

grpc:
  server:
    port: <grpc-port>
    health.enabled: true
```

Note that the `http-server-netty` and `http-client` dependencies were the main issues for me, which caused same problem.